# Проверка наличия файла при отправке google формы

Tags: google-apps-script

У меня есть скрипт, который создает новый (и удаляет старый) google документ.

```
function copyTemplate() {

    var form1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Form for dentist').next();
    formUrl = form1.getUrl();
    var formSome = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
    var copyOfFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName('statement_copy');

    while (copyOfFile.hasNext()) {
        var file = copyOfFile.next();
        DriveApp.removeFile(file);
    }

    newFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName('template').next().makeCopy('statement_copy');
    urlNew = newFile.getUrl();

    var docFile = DocumentApp.openByUrl(urlNew);

    formSome.setConfirmationMessage(urlNew);

}
```

Но этот скрипт работает очень долго. А иногда мне нужно отправить данные с формы прямо в этот файл (который создается). Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы нельзя было отправить форму, до тех пор пока файл не создался на диске?

Answer (score 1):

Операции на сервере выполняются последовательно. Поэтому, если не возникло ошибки, то файл уже точно есть. Можете писать в него что угодно.

Проверить существование файла вообще, можно только перехватив ошибку

```
function test() {
    Logger.log(isFileExist('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789-_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ'));
    Logger.log(isFileExist('1vSZehxRr68K7oTBbLnK8WAema1ebG1d6xahSWYsn2ct2L2hN8rpoW'));
}

function isFileExist(id) {
    return getFile(id).err ? false : true;
}

function getFile(id) {
    try {
        return DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    } catch (err) {
        return {
            err: err
        };
    }
}
```